# How to check for typos in a time series dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I have a user-input time series dataframe whose date column supposedly consists of all consecutive Mondays and Thursdays during an extended period of time stretched over few years. Specifically, "date" column (which is the first column) has either one of these formats: "Monday mm/dd/yyyy" or "Thursday mm/dd/yyyy". (The first few rows of the series are shown as an example even though there is no typo. One can imagine that having a much much longer period of time stretched over few years, it is more likely to encounter typos)

```
Monday 07/31/2023
Thursday 07/27/2023
Monday 07/24/2023
Thursday 07/20/2023
Monday 07/17/2023
Friday 07/13/2023
Thursday 07/10/2023
Monday 07/06/2023
Thursday 07/03/2023
Monday 06/29/2023
```

I would like to check this column against the following tests as concise as possible:

1. day portion of rows are alternating; no single day is repeated among any two neighboring rows.
2. There is a difference of 3 or 4 days between the date portion of any two neighboring rows.
3. In each row, day and date match based on the calendar; whether a specific datetime object, mm/dd/yyyy is actually a "Monday" or a "Thursday".

Comment: Please provide your input as reproducible text, not image.

Comment: @Ash, do you want to check if the actual or if the provided day is a Monday or a Thursday?

Comment: @DataJanitor, both checks are required. While the only valid options are Mon or Thur, they should actually be valid weekdays in the specified dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
tmp = df['date'].str.split(expand=True)

# are the dates valid?
check1 = (pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%A %m/%d/%Y')
            .dt.strftime('%A %m/%d/%Y')
            .eq(df['date']).all()
          )

# are the days a succession of Monday/Thursday?
check2 = tmp[0].eq(np.tile(['Monday', 'Thursday'], len(tmp)//2)[:len(tmp)]).all()

# are the time differences a succession of alternating 3/4 days?
s = pd.to_datetime(tmp[1], format='%m/%d/%Y').diff(-1).iloc[:-1]
check3 = (    (set(s.iloc[:2].dt.days) == {3, 4})
          and s.iloc[2:].eq(s.shift(2).iloc[2:]).all()
         )

print(check1, check2, check3)
# False False True
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['Monday 07/31/2023',
                            'Thursday 07/27/2023',
                            'Monday 07/24/2023',
                            'Thursday 07/20/2023',
                            'Monday 07/17/2023',
                            'Friday 07/13/2023',
                            'Thursday 07/10/2023',
                            'Monday 07/06/2023',
                            'Thursday 07/03/2023',
                            'Monday 06/29/2023']})
```

If you want to identify the offending rows:

```
tmp = df['date'].str.split(expand=True)

# are the dates valid?
check1 = (pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%A %m/%d/%Y')
            .dt.strftime('%A %m/%d/%Y')
            .eq(df['date'])
          )

def alternating(s, cat):
    s = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(s, categories=cat).codes, index=s.index)
    N = len(cat)-1
    return s.eq((s+N).mod(N+1).shift(N).fillna(s)) & s.between(0, N)

# are the days a succession of Monday/Thursday?
# this flags False if the current or previous day in not alternating M/T
check2 = alternating(tmp[0], cat=['Monday', 'Thursday'])

# are the time differences a succession of alternating 3/4 days?
check3 = alternating(pd.to_datetime(tmp[1], format='%m/%d/%Y').diff(-1).dt.days.iloc[:-1],
                     cat=[3, 4]
                    ).reindex(tmp.index, method='ffill')


df['valid_date?'] = check1
df['Mon/Thu?'] = check2
df['3/4 days'] = check3
df['invalid?'] = ~(check1 & check2 & check3)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                  date  valid_date?  Mon/Thu?  3/4 days  invalid?
0    Monday 07/31/2023         True      True      True     False
1  Thursday 07/27/2023         True      True      True     False
2    Monday 07/24/2023         True      True      True     False
3  Thursday 07/20/2023         True      True      True     False
4    Monday 07/17/2023         True      True      True     False
5    Friday 07/13/2023        False     False      True      True
6  Thursday 07/10/2023        False     False      True      True
7    Monday 07/06/2023        False      True      True      True
8  Thursday 07/03/2023        False      True      True      True
9    Monday 06/29/2023        False      True      True      True
```

Comment: this is very interesting solution however I am having an error message saying ValueError: unconverted data remains when parsing with format "%A %m/%d/%Y": " ", at position 8. You might want to try:  
    - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
    - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
    - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this

Comment: @Ash interesting, I didn't have the issue. In my case the incorrect days were just ignored. This might depend on the pandas version. If you're just interested in a yes/no answer then catch the exception with try/except and consider the data invalid. If you want to run all checks, add `errors='coerce'` as parameter to `to_datetime`. Also there is a possibility that you real data contains dates with a different format.

Comment: You can check for invalid dates using: `df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%A %m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce').isna(), 'date'].unique()`. What is the output?

Comment: It is a list of 45 elements in the format "%A %m/%d/%Y " where there is an empty space at the end of all the strings.

Comment: That's why, when providing `format` an exact match is expected. You can pre-process the column with `df['date'] = df['date'].str.strip()` to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

**Your data.**
I added another date at the end so it has a repeated day, too:

```py
data = {'date': ['Monday 07/31/2023', 'Thursday 07/27/2023', 'Monday 07/24/2023',
                 'Thursday 07/20/2023', 'Monday 07/17/2023', 'Friday 07/13/2023',
                 'Thursday 07/10/2023', 'Monday 07/06/2023', 'Thursday 07/03/2023',
                 'Monday 06/29/2023', 'Monday 06/22/2023']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**The checks:**

```py
# Split the day and date into separate columns
df[['provided_day_of_week','date']] = df['date'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Test 1: Check that the days are alternating
df['day_shift'] = df['provided_day_of_week'].shift(-1)
df['not_repeated_day_of_week'] = (df['provided_day_of_week'] != df['day_shift']) | df.index.isin([df.index[-1]])

# Test 2: Check the difference between consecutive dates is 3 or 4
df['date_diff'] = df['date'].diff(-1).dt.days.abs()
df['consecutive_date_diff_3_or_4'] = df['date_diff'].isin([3,4]) | df.index.isin([df.index[-1]])

# Test 3: Check the day of week matches the parsed date
df['actual_day_of_week'] = df['date'].dt.day_name()
df['day_of_week_correct'] = (df['actual_day_of_week'] == df['provided_day_of_week'])

# Test 4: Check the day of week is Monday or Thursday
df['day_of_week_is_monday_or_thursday'] = df['provided_day_of_week'].isin(['Monday', 'Thursday'])

# Check if all tests pass
df['all_tests_pass'] = df[['not_repeated_day_of_week', 'consecutive_date_diff_3_or_4', 'day_of_week_correct', 'day_of_week_is_monday_or_thursday']].all(axis=1)
```

**The result** is a nice dataframe which gives you the results of all the checks and its intermediate steps:

| date | provided_day_of_week | day_shift | not_repeated_day_of_week | date_diff | consecutive_date_diff_3_or_4 | actual_day_of_week | day_of_week_correct | day_of_week_is_monday_or_thursday | all_tests_pass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-31 00:00:00 | Monday | Thursday | True | 4 | True | Monday | True | True | True |
| 2023-07-27 00:00:00 | Thursday | Monday | True | 3 | True | Thursday | True | True | True |
| 2023-07-24 00:00:00 | Monday | Thursday | True | 4 | True | Monday | True | True | True |
| 2023-07-20 00:00:00 | Thursday | Monday | True | 3 | True | Thursday | True | True | True |
| 2023-07-17 00:00:00 | Monday | Friday | True | 4 | True | Monday | True | True | True |
| 2023-07-13 00:00:00 | Friday | Thursday | True | 3 | True | Thursday | False | False | False |
| 2023-07-10 00:00:00 | Thursday | Monday | True | 4 | True | Monday | False | True | False |
| 2023-07-06 00:00:00 | Monday | Thursday | True | 3 | True | Thursday | False | True | False |
| 2023-07-03 00:00:00 | Thursday | Monday | True | 4 | True | Monday | False | True | False |
| 2023-06-29 00:00:00 | Monday | Monday | False | 7 | False | Thursday | False | True | False |
| 2023-06-22 00:00:00 | Monday |  | True | nan | True | Thursday | False | True | False |

Comment: Checking the failing rows was not part of the question, that said if this is needed my answer also does that if you remove `all`. Nevertheless, I updated my answer with an improved approach (to check for any arbitrary alternating values)

Comment: @DataJanitor,  error saying "line 46, in checkValidity2       
    df[['provided_day_of_week','Dfate']] = df['Dfate'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
  ...
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3980, in _setitem_array       
    check_key_length(self.columns, key, value)
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexers\utils.py", line 392, in check_key_length
    raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"

Comment: @Ash When running the code above in jupyter notebook, I don't get an error with `NumPy` version `1.21.2`, `Pandas` version `1.5.2` and `Python` version `3.11.4`. Do you get an error when running my code above?

Comment: @DataJanitor, I am still getting error. I think it has to do with the python 3.8.X version that I am using for my specific environment.